# event.target.files array - where is this documented?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am looking for any official documentation that describes properties, including files[], of event.target in JavaScript/jQuery.

I've found the documentation on event.target, but none that list target's properties, such as files[].

Thank you.

Comment: Well, the properties `event.target` has depends on the element type of the target. E.g. `files` is a property of `<input>` elements: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement. If the target is a [`<a>` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLAnchorElement), you can access its `href` property, etc.

Comment: Thanks Felix King. That's what I was looking for.